# Android - how to add a background without scaling?

Tags: android, background

I want to add a background for my app. I tried both adding

```
<ImageView 
          android:contentDescription="@string/background_description"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
          android:src="@drawable/bg"/>
```

to my XML files and also using android:background, but both had this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK547.jpg

I actually want it to look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GO5R.jpg

Also, what do I have to do to make it look like this on different screen densities/resolutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to scale it but maintaining its width/height ratio then use:

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

To get the following:

```
<ImageView 
          android:contentDescription="@string/background_description"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
          android:layout_width="match_parent" 
          android:layout_height="match_parent" 
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:src="@drawable/bg"/>
```

You can get more information in the [Android ScaleType Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).
Also, you should not use `"fill_parent"` for any layout_width or layout_height, since it's deprecated. Instead you should use `"match_parent"`, as in the code above.

Comment: I added android:scaleType="fitCenter", and changed fill_parent to match_parent, but it's still the same!

Answer (score 0):

if you add this line to your imageview in xml

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

it will scale the image you are using to fit the imageview exactly

and for different screen resolutions fill your different drawable folders with the same image just at the resolutions youd like for different devices

Answer (score 0):

You may also do this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >
```

or else :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_cntent" >
```

Also Move your *.png file to drawable-nodpi folder for best results.

Will look like:

Tablets:

https://lh5.ggpht.com/nz7Nwa3tbCBYMqWcaY6hPtn-vRR4LJiT7RRN77irCzzI4ycUSXmVRcRnbwKZwPeoPQ=h310

Mobile phones:

https://lh3.ggpht.com/UbKPaaAgDkgrNLw3jTPai1BUW0JI8drD1jxuI_QlYBV2blVLjuPdXrV1-n9jJFWsEJS5=h900